# Alternative ways to manage lots of Passwords since Lastpass was hacked & now acquired

Tags: password-management, lastpass

There is a lot of debate on Reddit and other sites about whether the hack was or was not bad based on lack of salt to uncover the password hashes. Also, LogMeIn seems to have poor reputation & ratings as a reliable company.

I read a lot about KeePass in sync with DropBox/ G Drive/ OwnCloud etc.

There are old threads on SU about options of easy of use but not sure what 'Information Security' experts from here would say?

What would be good ways to manage App & Web Site passwords that are:

- Convenient & Usable - Ease of Use
- Better/ more securely stored
- Can be used for Individuals

Bonus:

- As well as groups/ teams for shared resources in an SMB

Comment: use SSO with multi-factor authentication

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your threat model.  Depending on what information you're protecting (and who you're protecting it against), Lastpass is just fine.  With a different model, you can use KeePass on a standalone, airgapped, encrypted Unix machine and pray to God your info is safe.

Lastpass is fine for your recipe web site account.  To some extent, they're excellent for even other personal consumer account protection.  Remember, Lastpass uses "zero-knowledge" encryption, so by design, the fact that they host your password data is no different from one of the alternatives you mentioned....

Which is KeePass + your cloud service account. I really have no idea what advantage you gain by doing this instead of just using Lastpass anyway.  Seriously, what's the difference?

KeePass stored on your local machine will be about as secure as your machine (or any local media the password database is stored) is.

The best way to approach the problem is to do your own personal risk management analysis. That just means... figure out what's most critical to protect.  Figure out whats less important, and finally what's least important. Consider what/who you're protecting that data against, and *then* plan your defense strategy accordingly.

It really should (and does) depend on all these factors combined. There is no one perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/).  If you want all members of your group to have access to the passwords, you can simply share the .kdbx file via the LAN.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [Sticky Password](http://www.stickypassword.com) to try out. They have WiFi sync, Cloud sync or offline mode. Plus lifetime licensing.